# Массивы с числовыми индексами JS

Tags: javascript

Создайте калькулятор для введённых значений

Напишите код, который:

1. Запрашивает по очереди значения при помощи prompt и сохраняет их в массиве.
2. Заканчивает ввод, как только посетитель введёт пустую строку, не число или     нажмёт «Отмена».
3. **При этом ноль 0 не должен заканчивать ввод, это разрешённое число.**
4. Выводит сумму всех значений массива

```js
(function() {
  var arr = [],
    res = 0,
    calc;

  do {
    calc = +prompt('Введите число', '');
    if (calc == '' || calc == null || isNaN(calc)) break;
    arr.push(calc);
  } while (true);

  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    res += arr[i];
  }

  return res;
})()
```

**Как выполнить третье условие??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
(function() {
  var heap = [],
      tmp;

  do{
    tmp = prompt('Введите число', '');
    // Пусто или null или NaN (0 - это число, так что спокойствие, только спокойствие!)
    if(tmp === '' || tmp === null || isNaN(tmp)) break;
    // Если проверка не выбросила из цикла, добавляем в кучу как Number
    heap.push(+tmp);
  }while(true);

  alert(heap.reduce((a, e) => a + e));
})();
```

Comment: Спасибо! Только вот интересно то, что Я так же ее решил с (===), но браузер почему то зависал))?

Comment: @fara, Зависал от явно из-за плохого цикла, который потенциально бесконечный. Строгое равенство не может повесить вкладку/браузер. А если может, то это сразу на премию Барвина - как Дарвина, только в браузерах :)

Answer (score 0):

Проверять введённую строку до её приведения к числу.

```
while ((calc = prompt('Введите число', '') /* присваивание */) && !isNaN(calc)) {
  calc = +calc;
```

Кстати, твой вариант и <kbd>Отмена</kbd> не обрабатывает.